# Infopath Form Template Conflict

Tags: sharepoint, forms, infopath, sharepoint-designer

We have a bunch of story libraries in Sharepoint 2003 for all of our different projects. We created a nice Stories Library with a bunch of useful views in Sharepoint. Then I exported it from Sharepoint designer and I use that template to create a library for each new project.
The problem is, the Infopath template always has the same ID. So when you open a story from a different project, you get a "Form Template Conflict" in InfoPath. The only way I found around this is to upload the form template to a Library of a unique name (this changes the Form template ID). But the problem with this is when I create a new, unique library I lose all the cool useful views which were included when I exported the Library.
 I tried changing the ID:
[Form Template Conflict - Same Form ID When Copying Template](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointinfopath/thread/e29253c4-5801-4818-bfd1-3993d35acd98/)

But this didn't work, when I published it, it reverted back to the generated one.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upgrade to SharePoint 2007